# integrating JS code into Framework7 project

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am a newbie front-end web developer, mainly working with Html, CSS, JS. Lately, I discovered Framework7 and instantly like it.

Before I decided to write this issue here I have spent days browsing the official docs, Framework7 forum, and StackOverflow but I didn’t get the whole idea of how framework7 actually works.

I used to integrate JS code easily in my Html files and this simple task seems so complicated with framework 7.

I tried to add a JS code directly on the bottom of each page of my project, but the code seems to work only on the index.html. So I tried to add separated JS files and call it from index.html also no luck

I want to integrate the following simple code on every page of my projects:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
  await admob.start()

  banner = new admob.BannerAd({
    adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy',
  })

  await banner.show()
}, false)

document.addEventListener('deviceready', async () => {
      await admob.start()
    
      interstitial = new admob.InterstitialAd({
        adUnitId: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy',
      })
    
      await interstitial.load()
      await interstitial.show()
    }, false)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Any help guys??

Answer (score 0):

use this plugin with cordova
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro

```
// select the right Ad Id according to platform
  var admobid = {};
  if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { // for android & amazon-fireos
    admobid = {
      banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/xxx', // or DFP format "/6253334/dfp_example_ad"
      interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy'
    };
  } else { // for ios
    admobid = {
      banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/zzz', // or DFP format "/6253334/dfp_example_ad"
      interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxx/kkk'
    };
  }
```